# How to add parameters to User class in Flask-Security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I'm trying to add another column in my User class for an API key.  However, I get an error with my kwargs when using Flask-Security.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'usermod'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    api_key = db.Column(db.String(256))
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users, backref=db.backref(
        'users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Furthermore, I'm trying to use my own `generate_key()` function to fill the field for the `api_key` for each user after registration.  This is given that I am using Flask-Security's built-in `app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True` field.  I'm not really sure how to override Flask-Security's settings to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this by simply keeping the User class as above. But to add my own function I had to use signals like so:

```
@signals.user_confirmed.connect_via(app)
def user_confirmed_sighandler(app, user):
    user.api_key = generate_key()
    return
```

This occurs after the user confirms their registration in email as opposed to at registration time (in which case you would use `@signals.user_registered.connect_via(app)`.